# Haskell dot operator: what difference does it make exactly?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, operators

I'm confused about a thing with the Haskell dot operator. What I have read about it is that it basicly creates a new function, composed of 2 other functions. E.g.:

```
f(g x) = f . g
```

(Omitting the parameter)

However, what'd be the difference if I just ommited the dot as well? Like:

```
f . g =? f g
```

Because in both cases g will be applied to the argument(s) passed to it, then f will be applied to that result.

So I don't see the difference between those two, but maybe there's a difference or there would be one when it's more complex? But I don't see it right now so if anyone could help me out on this it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: NO, function application is left associative, hence `f g x` is `(f g) x` and not `f (g x)`

Comment: I don't understand what (f g) x means though... Won't it give the same result as f(g x)?

Comment: Got it, it'd be g passed to f as an argument that'll be used in f's calculations directly (which possibly wouldn't make any sense).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression

```
h = f . g
```

creates a new function *h(...)* which is *f(g(...))*. This can be done without even calling `f`. However,

```
h = f g
```

passes `g` to `f` and assigns the result of that to `h`. In this case, `f` is called when `h` is evaluated.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the only difference lays within the evaluation and not in the result?

Comment: No, the result is totally different. I suggest trying a few expressions and see what happens.

Comment: I tried for example: h = sqrt . sum;
but then I got as result that h [1,2] = sqrt sum [1,2]. So I did get the same result, I guess I'm misinterpreting something...

Comment: Yes, but `h = sqrt sum` means something entirely different (eg. trying to take the square root of a function itself, which is nonsense).

Comment: @user2999349 The Haskell expression `sqrt sum [1,2]` will not compile because it is parsed equivalently to `sqrt (sum) ([1,2])`, where `sum` and `[1,2]` are both arguments to `sqrt`.  The expression `(sqrt . sum) [1, 2]` will compile because it is composing the functions `sqrt` and `sum`, resulting in a function that accepts a list of numbers and outputs the square root of their sum.

Comment: So if I get it right, f . g composes a new function which in fact does the same as f (g x) when applied to an argument x?

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks I think I got it now!

Comment: However, why wouldn't sqrt . sum [1,2] execute?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a proof of them being different:

```
Prelude> (const . id) True False
True
Prelude> (const id) True False
False
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to be careful about reducing these definitions.

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

this is how it is defined; nothing else. In particular, it is *not* `f g x` which is the same as `(f g) x` by definition.

In `f (g x)` `g` expects an argument and produces a value; `f` expects an argument and gets that value that `(g x)` produced; all is well.

But if *with the same functions* we write `(f g) x` then `f` receives `g` - a function - as the value of its parameter. Presumably it expected something else, a number say. And then the value it returns will be used as a function, and called with `x` as an argument! A total mismatch.

Comment: I got it now thanks! I was missing the fact that g is treated differently in both cases; as an argument that's directly used by f, or as a function that'll be firstly executed when an argument is passed to its composition with f.

Comment: However, why wouldn't f . g x compile? E.g. sqrt . sum [1,2]

Comment: because `(f . g x) y = f ((g x) y)`. e.g. `(sqrt . sum [1,2]) 7 = sqrt ((sum [1,2]) 7) = sqrt (3 7)` but `3` is not a function - it's a number. -- the expression `sqrt . sum [1,2]` == `sqrt . 3` also doesn't make sense, because `(.)` composes two functions, but 3 is not a function.

Comment: what you mean is `sqrt $ sum [1,2] = sqrt $ 3 = sqrt 3` because that's how `$` is defined: `f $ x = f x`.

Comment: in Haskell, "makes sense" means that the types fit; and "doesn't make sense" means there's a type mis-match. Haskell checks that the types match for each and every expression; and if not - it rejects such misformed expressions. in particular, the type of (.) is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`. I.e. it expects two functions, where the type produced by the 2nd function is the same as the type expected by the first as its argument. And it returns a new function, that expects same input as the second function, and produces same output as the first: `(f . g) x = f (g x)`.